# Xrandr no entry for DSI Display

Tags: nvidia, display, xrandr

I'm using a Nvidia  Jetson TX2 with HDMI and DSI porta.
I've got a working mipi DSI Display (created with custom device tree). The DSI display echoes the console output to the HDMI monitor while booting.
After booting, the HDMI monitor shows the Ubuntu desktop and the DSI display only show an console TTY3.
Xrandr has only HDMI monitor entry. How can I activate an desktop on the DSI display?

Ubuntu 16.04 with Linux for Tegra 27.1

```
dmesg | grep tegradc<br />
```

> [    1.728801] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay: Display dc.15200000
>   registered with id=0
>  [    1.729096] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay:
>   DT parsed successfully
>  [    1.736386] tegradc
>   15200000.nvdisplay: vblank syncpt # 7 for dc 0
>  [    1.736391] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay: vpulse3 syncpt # 8 for dc 0
>  [
>   1.738119] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay: DSI: HS clock rate is 184500
>  [    1.739795] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay: probed
>  [
>   2.369020] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay: fb registered
>  [    2.415897] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay: Link compression not supported by the panel
>  [    2.847188] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay: Window 0
>   assigned to head 0
>  [    3.231500] tegradc 15200000.nvdisplay:
>   Window 1 assigned to head 0
>  [    3.248197] tegradc
>   15200000.nvdisplay: Window 2 assigned to head 0
>  [    3.257993] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Display dc.15210000 registered with
>   id=1
>  [    3.281380] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: DT parsed
>   successfully
>  [    3.290612] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: vblank
>   syncpt # 11 for dc 1
>  [    3.300023] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay:
>   vpulse3 syncpt # 12 for dc 1
>  [    4.157752] tegradc
>   15210000.nvdisplay: probed
>  [    4.178653] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: fb registered
>  [    4.226677] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Link compression not supported by the panel
>  [    4.258682] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 3 assigned to head
>   1
>  [    4.273576] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 4 assigned
>   to head 1
>  [    4.289849] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 5
>   assigned to head 1
>  [    4.539597] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay:
>   hdmi: edid read failed
>  [    4.539642] tegradc
>   15210000.nvdisplay: hdmi: using fallback edid
>  [    4.539645] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: vrr_setup failed
>  [    5.297199]
>   tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: hdmi: plugged
>  [   12.497070] tegradc
>   15210000.nvdisplay: blank - powerdown
>  [   12.643425] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: unblank
>  [   12.648371] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Link compression not supported by the panel
>  [   12.664122] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 3 assigned to head
>   1
>  [   12.680784] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 4 assigned
>   to head 1
>  [   12.697467] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 5
>   assigned to head 1
>  [   13.746888] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay:
>   unblank
>  [   18.451538] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: blank -
>   powerdown
>  [   18.568106] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: unblank [   18.576291] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Link compression not
>   supported by the panel
>  [   18.587576] tegradc
>   15210000.nvdisplay: Window 3 assigned to head 1
>  [   18.604241] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 4 assigned to head 1
>  [
>   18.620907] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: Window 5 assigned to head 1
>  [   18.686606] tegradc 15210000.nvdisplay: unblank

Answer (score 0):

Desktop is now enabled after editing the /ect/X11/xorg.conf